# AJAX post for each time a checkboc is clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, each

I have this table of Items inside my form and I need ,everytime that I click the checkbox to send an AJAX post.
The problem is that the AJAX post is being sent ONLY for the first item.

I have read other Questions in here, but I cannot wrap my head around a solution, since none of them quite answermy problem.

Also all of this is in my django/python app if this can be of any assistance.

Thanks!

**My Form/table:**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'myapp:ajax-function' %}">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Number: <input type="text" name="number" />
      </td>
      <td>
        Title: <input type="text" name="title" />
      </td>
      <td>
        Insert:<input id="check" type="checkbox" data-id={{ doc.id }} name="checkebox"/>
      </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

**My AJAX:**

```
$("#check").each(function(){
  $(this).on("click", function(){
      var checked = $('#check').val();
      var message_id = $('#check').attr('data-id');


      $.ajax({
               url : "{% url 'myapp:ajax-function' %}", 
               //async: false,
               type : "POST",
               data:{
               'csrftoken':getCookie('csrftoken'),
               checked:checked,
               message_id:message_id},

         success : function(result) {
             console.log(result); // sanity check

         },


         error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
         console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
         },

      });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

element Id must occure only one time. assign a class to your checkboxes and change the selector:

```html
 Insert:<input class="check" type="checkbox" data-id={{ doc.id }} name="checkebox"/>
```

```
  $(".check").each(function(){
//........
```